# Invalid JSON error

Tags: json

I am writing a json file, but I am getting errors when I try to validate it online. What is wrong with the code ?

```
"document":
{

    "2009":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "2009 Annual Report",
            "version": 2,
            "timestamp": 1222222,
            "sessions": [
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "2009 Annual Report",
            "version": 2,
            "timestamp": 1222222,
            "sessions": [
            ]
        }
     ],

    "2010":
    [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "2010 Annual Report",
            "version": 2,
            "timestamp": 1222222,
            "sessions": [
            ]
        }
     ],
    "2011":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "2011 Annual Report",
            "version": 2,
            "timestamp": 1222222,
            "sessions": [
            ]
        }
     ]
}
```

Comment: use this in the future: http://www.jsonlint.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even the top-level object has to start and end with braces:

```
{
    "document": {
        "2009": [
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just forgot to put the curly brace at the begining of the array.
Now your code look like.

```
**{**
  "document":
 [

 { "2009":
 [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "2009 Annual Report",
        "version": 2,
        "timestamp": 1222222,
        "sessions": [
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "2009 Annual Report",
        "version": 2,
        "timestamp": 1222222,
        "sessions": [
        ]
    }
 ],

"2010":
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "2010 Annual Report",
        "version": 2,
        "timestamp": 1222222,
        "sessions": [
        ]
    }
 ],
"2011":
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "2011 Annual Report",
        "version": 2,
        "timestamp": 1222222,
        "sessions": [
        ]
    }
 ]
 }
 ]
 **}**
```

Check it. You got my point?